# How to add cell elements of 2 columns in libreOffice Calc Macro?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

I have 2 columns say column `G` and column `H`. Each one has different numeric values till `1449` rows. Now, I want to add corresponding cell elements at every row to get a new column. Is there any function to do it because simple `+` is not working in `.DataArray()` function.

```
Sub updateSTOCK

  Dim my_range,my_range2

  my_range=ThisComponent.Sheets(3).getCellRangebyName("H5:H1449")
  my_range2=ThisComponent.Sheets(3).getCellRangebyName("G5:G1449")

  my_range.Data=my_range.Data+my_range2.Data    ***----> This line gives error***

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome! Do you want replace cells in H column with sum of H and G? And you don't want do it manually with Paste Special - Add?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you **must** perform addition for each of the lines; group operations on range values are not supported

```
Sub updateSTOCK()
Dim oSheets As Variant
Dim oSheet3 As Variant
Dim oCellRangeByName As Variant
Dim oDataArray As Variant
Dim i As Long
    oSheets = ThisComponent.getSheets()
    oSheet3 = oSheets.getByIndex(3)
    oCellRangeByName = oSheet3.getCellRangeByName("H5:G1449")
    oDataArray = oCellRangeByName.getDataArray()
    For i = LBound(oDataArray) To UBound(oDataArray)
        oDataArray(i)(1) = oDataArray(i)(0) + oDataArray(i)(1)
    Next i
    oCellRangeByName.setDataArray(oDataArray)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I kept on searching for a direct way without having any loops.

Comment: Without having any loops? No problem! Record with macrorecorder this steps: select range G5:G1449, copy, select range H5:H1449, Paste Special with option Add (like it was describe in first comment). It will work without any loops

Comment: Now I have multiple options to perform the task. Thanks!